# How can I call a parent function which would use the subclass's overriden final variables?

Tags: java

Relevant code from my first class:

```
protected static final float MAX_HEALTH = 100.0f;
protected static final float MIN_HEALTH = 0.0f;

public void modifyHealth(float enteredAmount)
{
    if (health + enteredAmount > MAX_HEALTH )
    {
        health = MAX_HEALTH;
    }
    else if (health + enteredAmount < MIN_HEALTH)
    {
        health = MIN_HEALTH;
    }
    else
    {
        health += enteredAmount;
    }
}
```

Second class which extends the first class:

```
private final float MAX_HEALTH = 500.0f;
```

When I call the modifyHealth method on the second class, I want the health to be able to increase beyond 100, however currently it still uses the parent classs' final variable value. How can I make it so that the health can increase up to 500, while keeping both the variables final?

Comment: That doesn't work for fields. Use and override a (protected) method for that.

Comment: @f1sh I thought of this overriding themethod in the second class but that would mean copy pasting the whole method, and there's got to be a better way

Comment: @Aominè you are correct, i was thinking of protected. It's late :(

Comment: there is a `final` keyword there, do you know what it means?

Comment: @karakfa that's part of my question, if I was dealing with normal variables I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: You could just make the method take another param instead of using a class variable.

Comment: @csm_dev That would be worse than using a variable that isn't final. I want to keep it final if at all possible.

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly that is worse? Is this some code you are exposing to the public where they might modify the values of the variables? Or are you in full control of it?

Comment: super class is not designed for extension.  There might be a reason why it was set `private` and `final`.  Those variables are practically constants.  If you own the super class, change your design.

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition to 
    protected float MAX_HEALTH = 100.0f;

And override in the subclass. That way you can still use the method with different MAX_HEALTH value.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by others, think about changing the design (if you are in control of it). Otherwise you could use Reflection to access the field and change its value like:

```
Field field = myParentclass.getDeclaredField("MAX_HEALTH");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.setFloat(yourInstance, 500.0f);
```